# Equivalence between $(x \wedge y) \Rightarrow z$ and $(\neg{z} \wedge y) \Rightarrow \neg{x}$.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Consider the following proposition:

$$(x \wedge y) \Rightarrow z.$$

Is it true that, if the previous holds, then also

$$(\neg{z} \wedge y) \Rightarrow \neg{x}$$

is valid (equivalent to first one)?

Is so, is there a name for this "logical rule"?

Obviously, $x \Rightarrow z$ is equivalent to $\neg z \Rightarrow \neg x.$ Adding the clause $y$ does not seem to have any influence.

---

**Step-by-step derivation**

$$(x \wedge y) \Rightarrow z ~\text{yields to}\\\
\neg(x \wedge y) \vee z ~\text{yields to}\\
\neg x \vee \neg y \vee z ~\text{yields to}\\
(z \vee \neg y) \vee \neg x ~\text{yields to}\\
\neg(\neg z \wedge y) \vee \neg x ~\text{yields to}\\
(\neg z \wedge y) \Rightarrow \neg x.$$

Comment: Looks good to me. I suspect the answer depends on your particular logical setup.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks for your comment. What do you mean with "particular logical setup"? I guess I'm using the "standard" one.

Comment: I just meant the steps depend on what your starting point is, for example implicational propositional calculus vs. the usual classical. Nothing deep. But I have no idea if there is a particular name for the above equivalence, it certainly does not have a common use name.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm working in the standard framework. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with a simple truth table generator; the output below, for the input $$((x \wedge y) \Rightarrow z) \Rightarrow ((\neg{z} \wedge y) \Rightarrow \neg{x})$$ might be interesting (well, I have fun with it).

The rows for the subformulas $(x \wedge y) \Rightarrow z$ and
$(\neg{z} \wedge y) \Rightarrow \neg{x}$ show that both are false only when $x$ and $y$ are true and $z$ is false, so the top level implication I used actually goes both ways and, yes, they're logically equivalent.

If $y$ is false, both formulas are sort of trivially true; as you noted, when $y$ is true, it reduces to the contrapositive with respect to $x$ and $z$:

$$(x \Rightarrow z) \Leftrightarrow (\neg{z} \Rightarrow \neg{x})$$

```
        x         |||||||||
        y         |||||||||
        z         |||||||||
------------------+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
       x∧y        |||||||||
      x∧y⇒z       |||||||||
       ¬z         |||||||||
      ¬z∧y        |||||||||
       ¬x         |||||||||
     ¬z∧y⇒¬x      |||||||||
(x∧y⇒z)⇒(¬z∧y⇒¬x) |||||||||
```

Comment: Thanks for the truth table!